# Update a value with another from previous cell sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where I need to
1. look & find any date that is equal to 1900-01-01
2. Replace it with the value from the previous cell

[image]

Comment: Other than how they look on a screen, a database table doesn't have much in common with a spreadsheet. Databases store data in _unordered sets_, so "previous" doesn't have any real meaning until you impose an order through your query, hence the `ORDER BY` clauses in the proposed answers. Also, tables don't have "cells", they have rows and columns. Changing your mindset makes it easier to conceptualize problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.id,
       coalesce(nullif(date, '01-01-1900'),
                lag(date) over (order by id)
               ) as date
from t;
```

EDIT:

If you want to update the value, use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, lag(date) over (order by id) as prev_date
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set date = prev_date
    where date = '1900-01-01';
```